How to make a bootable USB flash drive that functions like a fully-fledged computer?
I have been trying to do research into the problem, and I cannot seem to find any satisfactory answers out there on the web. What I'm basically trying to do is create a USB flash drive that I can plug into any machine and run like a normal computer, with files created on the machine saved in the USB stick rather than the RAM.
Creating regular installation media with Rufus allows me to boot into the OS, but it does not save files across sessions.
I'm trying to use the current version of NixOS w/ KDE Plasma for this, but I could probably use another Linux distro if necessary

This is very doable.  The keywords to google are "persistent live usb" - Here is 1 solution.  https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-persistent-live-usb/  - Also look at https://www.reddit.com/r/NixOS/comments/1d166zr/live_persistent_nixos_on_a_usb/

Tip: Cheap USB flash drives often don't support fast enough read/write speeds for small random (non-sequential) reads and writes to function well when used as a read/write boot device, so they can be painfully slow for this purpose. Be sure to pick a flash drive with fast random I/O speeds for this. If the read/write speeds a vendor quotes on a specs page don't say if they're sequential or random, assume they're for large sequential operations not small random operations. Good choices do exist, but you have to read reviews with performance tests and choose wisely.

To piggy-back on @Spiff's comment, you'll want to ensure it's listed what both the read and write speed is of the USB drive, as manufacturers who make high read throughout drives won't list the write speed when it's many factors lower of a throughput speed (e.g. 200MB Read, but only ~20MB Write). If a write speed isn't specified, it's an almost guarantee it has poor write performance. PNY has USB drives with high read and write speeds that are usually the most reasonably priced (they also have ones with poor write speeds, so it still applies to verify)

Yes, that's the default result when you install any Linux OS onto a USB stick. There is no difference between installing onto a USB disk and a SATA disk.
Being read-only is not an inherent property of USB installation – rather, "regular installation media" images are deliberately customized to work in a read-only mode. (For various reasons, but the fact that these images are still meant to work from read-only CDs is one of them.)
For example, the author of such a "live" image will edit the initramfs to set up a RAM-based overlayfs or unionfs at / on top of the regular filesystem, then they'll cram the entire installation into a read-only SquashFS image so that it could be put on FAT32 and/or copied to RAM. But if you do a plain installation to a USB stick this doesn't happen and it behaves just like a regular installation.
Some Linux distributions also offer persistence on top of a read-only "live USB" image (by adding a second overlayfs that stores just the modified files on disk), which might extend the USB stick's lifetime – it's a lot of extra complexity, but it does include some useful configuration such as not saving system logs on the disk, which is especially important for cheap USB sticks (but less so for "portable SSDs").
In conclusion, you could 1) do a regular installation to the USB stick, 2) disable the writing of system logs to /var/log (e.g. turn it into a tmpfs), 3) disable all other scheduled jobs (cron jobs and systemd timers) such as daily 'apt' updates, Flatpak updates, etc., 4) pre-install things like graphics drivers for all GPUs, etc.

It is easy to create a bootable Linux USB drive with persistence, e.g., following It's Foss directions.
That said, there might be some issues:

USB flash drives can be very slow to write data. This impacts user experience. Using a fast external SSD might help -- but some PC's cannot boot from an external SSD.
Since any changes made are retained, the USB drive might not be bootable in a second PC after being customized for the first, or the settings might be inappropriate (e.g., drivers for WiFi card, display settings).

